# Subprocess Python.. Stringing together commands

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess

I am writing a Python program that needs to return the active hosts scanned in one of my vulnerability scans. I have used this method before returning XML, but when I try to tack on these extra programs such as cut and grep I run into issues. Perhaps it doesn't like "pipes" | or maybe I am doing something completely wrong here with my commas but I have tried all sorts of things and cant seems to get it to return the result like it does when I run the command standalone from the command line. Thanks very much for any help that is provided.

```
def activeHostsQuery():
    args = ['curl', '-s', '-k', '-H', 'X-Requested-With: curl demoapp', '-u','username:password', 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=fetch&scan_ref=scan/1111111.22222&mode=brief&output_format=csv', '|', 'cut', '-d', '-f1', '|', 'sort', '|', 'uniq', '|', 'grep', '-E', '"\"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\""', '|', 'wc', '-l']

    activeHostsNumber = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return activeHostsNumber
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the "shell=True" argument to `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: activeHostsNumber = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=TRUE).communicate()[0] ..... this gives me a "global name "TRUE" not defined error

Comment: It needs to be 'True', not 'TRUE' - case matters.

Comment: curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information.. This is the message i get when i make those changes

Comment: The **right** way to do this is not to be using any shell commands at all.  Python can do all of what curl, cut, sort, grep and wc do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
def activeHostsQuery():
    args = ['curl', '-s', '-k', '-H', 'X-Requested-With: curl demoapp', '-u','username:password', 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=fetch&scan_ref=scan/1111111.22222&mode=brief&output_format=csv', '|', 'cut', '-d', '-f1', '|', 'sort', '|', 'uniq', '|', 'grep', '-E', '"\"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\""', '|', 'wc', '-l']

    activeHostsNumber = subprocess.Popen(" ".join("'%s'" % a for a in args), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return activeHostsNumber
```

**Edit:** added quotes around arguments.

**Another edit:** Ok, try making the command a single string:

```
def activeHostsQuery():
    cmd = 'curl -s -k -H \'X-Requested-With: curl demoapp\' -u username:password \'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=fetch&scan_ref=scan/1111111.22222&mode=brief&output_format=csv\' | cut -d, -f1 | sort | uniq | grep -E \'"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}"\' | wc -l'

    ctiveHostsNumber = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return activeHostsNumber
```

Comment: after making those adjustments it just returns a blank line and the program stops execution

Comment: Is it possible that i am not putting commas around the proper things in my args?

Comment: I don't think you need commas around anything. I made a change to my solution to add quotes around everything, since some of your arguments have spaces and special characters in them.

Comment: so i can just take all the commas and single quotes out of all the args?.. im trying that right now but not having much success

Comment: The `args` variable you have prepared is a list of strings. Each string must be surrounded by quotes and separated from the next one by a comma. But you don't want to pass a list of strings to `subprocess.Popen` when you're using the `shell=True` argument, you want to pass it a single string - which is why I have the `" ".join("'%s'" % a for a in args)` in my solution.

Comment: still not having much luck.. so you are saying to just put the list item between quotes, taking out all the original quotes and commas i had in there?

Comment: I've edited my answer to make the command a string explicitly.

Comment: I've made yet another edit to fix a problem with your `cut` command and remove an extra couple of quotes from your `grep` command.

Comment: SO it seems as if all the commands are running before curl has a chance to get the entire HTTP request back displaying all the CSV values.. why would the rest of the programs be trying to run before the data it is supposed to manipulate has yet to be returned?

Comment: Its working but its just not working on the returned curl data.. like when I run this command from the command line it normally takes about 8 - 10 seconds before I get the results back

Comment: Okay Awesome its working!! the only problem is that when i run grep i need to look for double quotes.. how do i make sure that these double quotes are still included in the search?

Comment: when i try to use the double quotes like i had originally with grep it gives me a "uniq: write error: Broken pipe"

Comment: the IP's im trying to grep out are in this format "192.168.1.1"

Comment: I've edited my answer yet another time to restore the double quotes to the argument to grep.

Answer (score 6):

The right way to string together commands -- if you want to keep the shell out of it, which you should -- is to create multiple Popen objects.

```
def activeHostsQuery():
    args1 = ['curl', '-s', '-k',
             '-H', 'X-Requested-With: curl demoapp',
             '-u','username:password',
             'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=fetch&scan_ref=scan/1111111.22222&mode=brief&output_format=csv']
    args2 = ['cut', '-d', '-f1']
    args3 = ['sort', '-u']
    args4 = ['grep', '-E', '"\"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\""']
    args5 = ['wc', '-l']

    p1 = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(args2, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p1.stdout.close()
    p3 = subprocess.Popen(args3, stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p2.stdout.close()
    p4 = subprocess.Popen(args4, stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p3.stdout.close()
    p5 = subprocess.Popen(args5, stdin=p4.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p4.stdout.close()
    activeHostsNumber = p5.communicate()[0]
    return activeHostsNumber
```

The advantage of this is that there's no shell involved -- you can substitute arbitrary variables into your argument lists without concern that they'll be string-split, misinterpreted, cause redirections, or anything else, and the distinctions between arguments you use in generating your lists will be honored.

Now, in *this particular* case, I'd do the whole thing in native Python -- there's no reason even to use curl when you have native HTTP libraries -- but knowing how to build pipelines with subprocess.Popen is useful in any event.

Comment: By the way -- I'm pretty sure the regex given to grep here is wrong. I didn't change it because it was given as part of the problem, but you probably want to strip one of the sets of double quotation marks surrounding, unless you really want egrep to require the matched string to start and end with `""`.

Comment: imho, this is the best way to do something like this in python.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question... but that's shell script.
If you want shell script pass an argument to sh -c (or bash or something)

```
    args = ['sh', '-c', 'curl -s -k -H X-Requested-With: curl demoapp -u','username:password https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=fetch&scan_ref=scan/1111111.22222&mode=brief&output_format=csv | cut -d -f1 | sort | uniq | grep -E "\"[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\"" | wc -l'


   count = int(cubprcess.check_output(args))
```

or use `shell=True` like some others suggested. This will definitely not work on Windows if you care about such things.

really you should probably do something like:

```
import requests
from csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import re

req=reqeusts.get(
    'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=fetch&scan_ref=scan/1111111.22222&mode=brief&output_format=csv',
    auth=('username','passoword'),
    headers={'X-Requested-With': 'curl demoapp'})

reader = csv.reader(StringIO(req.text))
count = 0
for line in reader:
    if re.match(r'.*\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.*',line[0]) is not None:
        count += 1

print count
```

Comment: `sh -c "one line" "another line"` doesn't actually process anything but the first line. The argument after `-c` is the script to run; the one after that is the `$0` passed to the script, the one after that is `$1`, etc.